# Using jquery tabs and changing languages with a blank tab

Tags: jquery, cookies, menu, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery to create a menu with switching of language between Chinese and English.

The tabs in the menu work well, however, there should be nothing in the language tab.

It should only switch languages and keep the content of the current active tab.

[**Here**](http://hkbesttutor.com/) is the website.

I have tried many methods but still cannot achieve that I want.

For example, `click()`, `tabs("active")`, `tabs("option", "selected")`.

I cannot find any example about using jquery tabs and changing languages with a blank tab.

Would anyone be kind to help me solve this problem?

My html code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Homepage"><span id="menu-homepage">Homepage</a></span></li>
        <li><a href="#Members"><span id="menu-members">Members</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tutors"><span id="menu-tutors">Tutors</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#NewJobs"><span id="menu-newjobs">New Jobs</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#TopTutors"><span id="menu-toptutors">Top Tutors</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tuition"><span id="menu-tuition">Tuition</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Questions"><span id="menu-questions">Questions</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#AboutUs"><span id="menu-aboutus">About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#ContactUs"><span id="menu-contactus">Contact Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Language"><span id="menu-language">中文版本</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Homepage">
        <?php require("homepage.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Members">
        <?php require("members.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Tutors">
        <?php require("tutors.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="NewJobs">
        <?php require("newjobs.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="TopTutors">
        <?php require("toptutors.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Tuition">
        <?php require("tuition.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Questions">
        <?php require("questions.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="AboutUs">
        <?php require("aboutus.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="ContactUs">
        <?php require("contactus.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Language">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my script code:

```
$("#menu-language").click(function(){
    var homepage, members, tutors, newjobs, toptutors;
    var tuition, questions, aboutus, contactus, language;
    if ($.cookie("lang") == "English") {
        $.cookie("lang", "Chinese");
        homepage = "網站首頁";  members = "會員專區";
        tutors = "導師專區";  newjobs = "最新工作";
        toptutors = "優秀導師";  tuition = "學費參考";
        questions = "常見問題";  aboutus = "關於我們";
        contactus = "聯絡我們";  language = "English";
    } else {
        $.cookie("lang", "English");
        homepage = "Homepage";  members = "Members";
        tutors = "Tutors";  newjobs = "New Jobs";
        toptutors = "Top Tutors";  tuition = "Tuition";
        questions = "Questions";  aboutus = "About Us";
        contactus = "Contact Us";  language = "中文版本";
    }
    $("#menu-homepage").html(homepage);
    $("#menu-members").html(members);
    $("#menu-tutors").html(tutors);
    $("#menu-newjobs").html(newjobs);
    $("#menu-toptutors").html(toptutors);
    $("#menu-tuition").html(tuition);
    $("#menu-questions").html(questions);
    $("#menu-aboutus").html(aboutus);
    $("#menu-contactus").html(contactus);
    $("#menu-language").html(language);

    switch ($.cookie("menu")) {
        case "Homepage" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 0);  break;
        case "Members" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 1);  break;
        case "Tutors" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 2);  break;
        case "NewJobs" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 3);  break;
        case "TopTutors" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 4);  break;
        case "Tuition" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 5);  break;
        case "Questions" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 6);  break;
        case "AboutUs" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 7);  break;
        case "ContactUs" : $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 8);  break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the div element with id language.
Now whenever, you click language tab, nothing will be displayed.
Also, if you can remove a tag with the id as language.

Comment: Someone in other forum has answered me.  Why not use it as real tab? You can watch the beforeActivate event to do the language switching and then send the user back to the ui.oldTab.